# Use Python and cmdkey add in Windows 10

Tags: python, cmd, windows-10

This is my Python code:

```
import os

os.system('cmdkey /add:TERMSRV/X.X.X.X/user:Administrator /pass:pwxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
os.system('mstsc /v:X.X.X.X')
os.system('cmdkey /delete:TERMSRV/X.X.X.X')
```

The code can open Remote Desktop correctly with an IP address, X.X.X.X.

But it also asks me to input a password.

Why can the cmdkey command not add the password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of bugs in the cmdkey syntax:

1. Instead of /add, you should be using

   ```
   /generic
   ```

   That identifies the computer or domain name that this entry will be associated with.
2. The space issue between X.X.X.X and `/user`.

So the solution should be:

```
os.system('cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/"IP.IP.IP.IP" /user:"username" /pass:"password")
```

In case you are in a LAN network, you can remove TERMSRV.

Refer to [the cmdkey reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc754243(v=ws.10)).